# set prefetch row size

Tags: java, oracle, jboss

How to set prefetch size in either oracle connection url or in jboss datasource file?

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
    <jndi-name>dsDS</jndi-name>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <local-transaction/>
    <user-name>*</user-name>
    <password>*</password>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <connection-url></connection-url>
    <connection-property name="SetBigStringTryClob">true</connection-property>
    <valid-connection-checker-class-name> org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker </valid-connection-checker-class-name>
    <exception-sorter-class-name> org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter </exception-sorter-class-name>
<track-statements>false</track-statements>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to set prefetch size through oracle connection. I had to get underlying connection through jboss managed connection, cast it to oracle connection and set prefetch size in that class.